# Show only the really extracted (non-skipped) files using tar

Tags: tar, output

I'm extracting daily backup archives. I want to see only the new files since the last day. The archives contain lot of already existing files, which I don't want to overwrite, so I use the `--skip-old-files` option, which is fine.

But I'd like to **list only** those files that were **actually extracted** and omit those that were skipped because they already exist.

### Example:

My current command is:

```
tar --verbose --skip-old-files --extract --file=2019-02-10.tar.gz
```

and the output is (where file1 and file2 were already exist and file3 was new):

```
file1.zip
tar: file1.zip: skipping existing file
file2.zip
tar: file2.zip: skipping existing file
file3.zip
```

I need only the file3.zip in the output. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm realizing that you have to hope that there are no *actual* files named "tar: file1.zip: skipping existing file", unless you carefully manage the stdout *and* stderr streams...

Comment: Yeah, I also realized that the complexity goes too high to solve this problem with a pure output text mangling solution. The best option would be if the tar command itself could support this type of output.

Comment: @JeffSchaller for tarballs that include slashes for the paths of files within, this is a non-issue, so an answer similar to your first thought could still be useful.

Comment: true, @Wildcard, but the example in the question shows path names that *don't* have slashes, so I'll pass. Feel free to take the idea and run with it, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the only process writing to the directory then you could create a temporary file, extract the files not in verbose mode, then look at those with a change time newer than the temp file

e.g.

```
MYTMP=$(mktemp)
tar --skip-old-files --extract --file=2019-02-10.tar.gz
find . -cnewer $MYTMP
rm $MYTMP
```

Comment: I will use the MYTMP to create a fixed name file (instead of temporary file) as a flag to avoid starting more than one instance. If the file exists then my script will do nothing.

Comment: I secretly hoped there is an solution for this in the tar command itself, but it's good workaround for me.

Comment: At first glance I thought this was a brittle/fragile approach, but on closer inspection and reading up on [how ctime can be modified](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39521489/5419599) this looks *very* reliable (with the noted exception if other processes are writing to the same directory).  +1, very nice.